# Multiline plot with seaborn from pandas dataframe with vector elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When plotting a `pandas` `DataFrame` using `seaborn`, I really like the grouping/categorizing keyword options that you are offered like `hue=` and `style=`:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3]],
                   'y':[[1,2,3],[4,4,8,3],[3,6,8]],
                   'cat1': ['x','y','x'],
                   'cat2': ['a','b','c']})

df[['x_mean','y_mean']] = df[['x','y']].applymap(np.mean)

# for a scatterplot of scalar values, I can categorize easily
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='x_mean', y='y_mean', style='cat1', hue='cat2')
```

[image]

However, this only works for scalar values like the calculated means. When I actually want to show `'y'` over `'x'` as multiple lines, I have to either:

- iterate over the rows:

```py
# for line plots, not so much
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    sns.lineplot(data=row, x='x', y='y', style='cat1', hue='cat2')
```

[image]

Obviously, `style` and `hue` don't work like this here anymore and I would have to define a mapping for each manually in advance. I don't even know how to create this grouped legend entries.

- the other option would be to explode `'x'` and `'y'`, but this is also very inconvenient for large arrays.

Is there any other way to achieve this more elegantly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot), after running [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) on `x`/`y`:

```
sns.relplot(data=df.explode(['x', 'y'], ignore_index=True),
            x='x', y='y',
            style='cat1', hue='cat2',
            kind='line',
           )
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had to adjust this to `df.explode(['x', 'y'], ignore_index=True)`, otherwise I would get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`. This works, however I am a bit reluctant to use explode, because in real life , `x` and `y` are very long. Is this the only way?

Comment: To my knowledge, yes. `Facetgrid` would have been a better candidate to avoid the `explode`, but [unfortunately it doesn't support `style`](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/1586) (you could however write your own wrapper derived from it). Keep in mind that `pandas` is not designed to use lists (objects) as items and works much better with scalars. You might want to rethink your data design.

Comment: I know, run into this all the time but so far couldn't come up with anything more useful. Each row of the dataframe holds a single simulation with all relevant parameters. This allows to easily filter the ones that I would like to compare. However, the actual results are time signals with a length of several thousands.

But I just checked, your solution (with the addition of that `ignore_index=True` keyword) works. If you adjust this, then I can accept your answer.